# I want to retrieve the value of the parameter of the previous intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow bot that asks for  firstname,lastname,dobday,dobmonth,dob year individually from the user(so I have 5 intents in DF and 5 seperate intent.js files for each field in webhook ).
I want to validate the dob in such a way that when the user gives the month ,bot should validate whether the user is entering the days in correct format.This should be in Nodejs

example:

Bot:Hi,please enter your first name
User:John
Bot:your last name
user:Sally
Bot:your dob month?
User:02
Bot:your dob day?
User:31
Bot:sorry,this is invalid dob

I created a seperate intents for each of the fields and validating in webhook for each field using nodejs.I am not sure how to proceed for this type of validation.For this,do I need to use any contexts or followup intents?If I have to validate dob day in a seperate .js file ,I need to retreive the month value retained from the user.

Till now:
I have validated the date of birth month that I get from the user .I am new to Javascript and node js.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to save the information in a context. then you can retrieve the data on whatever intent that is in the same context.

Comment: I used getcontext and tried this one also.This also works for me..Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer of @MizarConstanti, you can use the following for your entities:

- For date you can use entity `@sys.date`
- For first name `@sys.given-name`
- For last name `@sys.last-name`

NOTE: For given name and last name entities, these entities could only recognize the common names ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities)).

An alternative for getting dates and names is you can create training phrases in this manner and extract the information using the defined entities.

**Intent-> test intent**

[image]

[image]

**Intent -> getName**
[image]
[image]

If you are using library `dialogflow-fulfillment` in Dialogflow inline editor these entities could be called using this code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const axios = require('axios'); 

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });


function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
    // initial value of agent.parameters.date is 1994-07-29T12:00:00+08:00
    // thus the splitting done below
    const date = agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0];
    const year = agent.parameters.date.split('-')[0];
    const month = agent.parameters.date.split('-')[1];
    const day = agent.parameters.date.split('-')[2].split('T')[0];
    agent.add(`year: ${year}, month:${month}, day:${day}`);
  }

function getName(agent) {
    const lastName = agent.parameters.lastName;
    const firstName= agent.parameters.givenName;
    agent.add(`first: ${firstName}, last: ${lastName}`);
}  
  
  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('test intent', yourFunctionHandler);
  intentMap.set('getName', getName);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Test for date and name intent:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to get the variable from the Dialogflow without backend, then read it from the diagnostic info, if the information is watched you can get from the backend response.